# adding xml to button background gives error in android (visual studio IDE)

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I am trying to give custom style to a android-button in visual studio 2015 through 
android:background,,, but it gives an error saying "[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown> --->  "

I cannot understand why??

Here is my xml file (ButtonSigninStyle.xml)

```
<selector  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false">

<layer-list>
  <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
    <shape>
      <corners android:radius="2dp" />
      <solid android:color="#D6D6D6"/>
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp">
    <gradient android:angle="270" android:startColor="#4a6ea9"        android:endColor="#4a6ea9"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#bababa"/>
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp"/>
  </item>

</layer-list>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="true">

<layer-list>
  <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
    <shape>
      <corners android:radius="2dp" />
      <solid android:color="#D6D6D6"/>
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp">
    <gradient android:angle="270" android:startColor="#4a6ea9" android:endColor="#4a6ea9"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#bababa"/>
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp"/>
  </item>

</layer-list>
</item>

</selector>
```

Here is my axml file for the activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="100"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<TextView
    android:text="Create an Account"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtcreateaccount"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
<Button
    android:text="Sign in"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:id="@+id/signin_but"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ButtonSigninStyle"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:clickable="true" />
<TextView
    android:text="Or"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtor"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:textColor="#f99518"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
<Button
    android:text="Sign up"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:id="@+id/signup_but"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="#57db2f"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:clickable="true" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="true" />
  </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

*ButtonSigninStyle.xml resides in Resources->drawable->ButtonSigninStyle.xml

Answer (score 1):

Remove `/` from `android:background="@/drawable/ButtonSigninStyle"` it should be 
`android:background="@drawable/ButtonSigninStyle"`  in

```
<Button
    android:text="Sign in"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:id="@+id/signin_but"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ButtonSigninStyle"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

Comment: sorry, that was a typing mistake here, I am already doing what you said,